# Kivy - How to make an object accessible from both Kv Language child widgets and Python widget's classes?

Tags: python, kivy

I'd like to know how to access an instace object from a class I have defined from both my Kv Language child widgets and my widgets classes inside my Python file.

If I instantiate my object in my App's class, my Kv Language file has access to it and my widgets classes don't. But when I make this object global (outside my App's class), all my classes access it, but my Kv Language child widgets don't. I made the following code the make it clear:

My **Python** file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class Person():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def getName(self):
        return self.name

class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    def getPerson1Name(self):
        return person1.getName()

person1 = Person('Nik')

class MyApp(App):
    person2 = Person('Jackie')
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

My **Kv Language** file:

```
<MyLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: nameDisplay
        Button:
            text: 'Display person1\'s name'
            on_press: nameDisplay.text = root.getPerson1Name()
        Button:
            text: 'Display person2\'s name'
            on_press: nameDisplay.text = app.person2.getName()
```

As you can see, **person1** can be accessed from **MyLayout** class and **person2** from my Kv Language file, but if I swap these objects, it won't work. Does someone know how I'll make an object accessebile from these two mediums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [App.get_running_app()](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.get_running_app):

```
class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    def getPerson1Name(self):
        return App.get_running_app().person2.getName()
```

It's generally bad practice to use global variables.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! About the global variables, I know it's a bad habit, I used them because it was the only way I managed to access the objects from my widget classes, but it was annoying me haha